# How can i change a given parameter if it is not an acceptable option?

Tags: parameters, constructor

I am a beginner at Java and i have the following question:

For my assignment i have to keep track if a certain person is male of female. The two options are 'M' (male) or 'F' (female). If the given parameter is any other charachter then 'M' or 'F', it should become a 'U' (unkown).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is my code for further clarification:

```
public class Store
{
    private char gender;
    
    public Store(char gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement a check before storing the variable.

Check to see if gender either equals m or f, if not it is automatically 'u'.

```
public Store(char gender)
    {
        if(gender == m || gender == f){
            this.gender = gender;
        }
        gender = 'u';
    }
```

This is also considering that the input will definitely be a character, you might want to think about adding a check to make sure it's a valid parameter.